# Best way to evaluate each item inside a list

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a list of integers, let's say `myList`. I want to do something when every item is equal to one. The idea is to optimize this kind of code:

```
if myList[0] == 1 and myList[1] == 1 and ... :
        do something
```

Comment: make a boolean allOne, set it to True. Loop over every item, if it is 0, set it to false, and break out of the loop. continue with what you want

EDIT: while correct, you can use the all function..

Comment: `if all(element == 1 for element in myList):`?

Comment: yes!!! this is what i need to do... what exactly do the keyword "all"?

Comment: do not answer me ... i am looking for the response. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
if all(item == 1 for item in myList):
    do_something()
```

This is efficient because it will stop testing as soon as the `item == 1` condition fails.

---

FWIW, you *could* do it this way:

```
if all(map((1).__eq__, myList)):
    do_something()
```

However, the first way is much nicer to read. And it's generally considered bad style to call "dunder" methods like `__eq__` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `all`:

```
if all(x == 1 for x in myList):
    ...
```